# Change Firefox tab-switching  keyboard  shortcut

Tags: keyboard, firefox, web-browsing, switching

To move to the next tab in most browsers, you use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd>.

Then, to close it, you have to reach over to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

I don't like switching modifier keys like that; I'd prefer to just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> for both.
Is there a way to change the shortcuts so that both shortcuts use the control key? It would be great to switch this globally, but otherwise a solution for Firefox would be fine too.

Comment: This is not a site for rants. I've edited your question to remove the rant part. In the future, please focus on the question and not the rant. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: @Nathan: sorry if it sounded like a rant, but I thought saying that's it's illogical and un-ergonomical is pretty objective. Doesn't matter anyways. Edit: reread it, and maybe I overused "horrible" :D Sorry.

Comment: I don't see how you can think the control key is more ergonomic than the command key. I need to move my thumb 1 cm to press control, and all my fingers are still available to press the letter in the way I normally would. Combos like ctl-A and ctl-Tab require me to shift my hand.

Comment: @dazmax: I am only talking about this specific situation. You move to a tab with control-tab. To close it using control-W, you move only one finger over to the W from Tab. If you have to use command, you need to move one finger over to the W and the other over to the command key. Moving two fingers is less ergonomic than moving one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to your question, but you can also use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> etc for visiting each tab, as well as <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to go to the previous/next tab.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's a good alternative. As it looks I can't do exactly what I want I'll accept this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**This is the definitive answer.** Here are two official FireFox add-ons (plugins) that let you modify or define your own keyboard commands and shortcuts.

[Key config](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/key-config/)

[My Keyboard Navigator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/my-keyboard-navigator/)

Comment: I'm curious why you opened a bounty on a question that you answered (twice).

Comment: Because I'm a newbie here and I just wanted to test and see how the bounty system works!

Answer (score 0):

If you go in to System Preferences, you can then choose "Keyboard & Mouse" where you will be able to re-wire shortcuts. I'm writing this from my iPhone, so I can't give you detailed instructions, but googling "mac change keyboard shortcuts" gave me lots of guides describing how to do it, among which this one from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2490#l4

Answer (score 0):

I belive in Firefox you can use <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to view the open tabs.

Answer (score 0):

To change a keyboard shortcut that appears in an OS X application's menu:

System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts

Click the plus, and type the name of the command exactly as it appears in the menu, and choose a shortcut. (e.g. "Close Tab" and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)

I would recommend, however, using the OS X standard for changing tabs, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>]</kbd>, since you don't have to take your hands off home-row typing position. I believe it works for Firefox and most other tabbed applications.